# How to solve not enough GPU memory when traning big model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am running LSTM demo in tensorflow.

Cell output size 461*461*4*120=100MB （120 hidden nodes）

Softmax output size 461*461*4*256=200MB

But use Nvidia 960 (4G memory) to running this demo will exhaust all GPU-memory,Why?

If hidden nodes up to 1000, use doble GPU (Nvidia 1080) is hard to make this work ,How to figure it out?

Comment: You should probably provide more information about your problem. For example, what size is the training data, what error codes you are getting, etc.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a larger GPU